# Proving $\ln\left(\frac{b+1}{a+1}\right)<S<\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ given that $tS=Hb−Ha=\sum_{i=a+1}^b\frac{1}{i}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given positive integers $a$ and $b$ with $b>a$, and $S=S_b-S_a=\sum\limits_{i=a+1}^b\dfrac1i$, how do I prove that $\ln\dfrac{b+1}{a+1}<S<\ln\dfrac ba$?

This is what I've tried so far: I know that S is greater than the surface beneath [a, b] but less than the surface beneath [a + 1, b + 1], by drawing blocks of height 1/i beneath or above the graph of y = 1/x. How do I put this into math? I've used $\displaystyle\int_s^t\frac{\mathrm dx}x=\ln\frac ts$, but I'm still stuck on how I should put it into a whole coherent piece.

Comment: This is not "abstract algebra".

Comment: The correct statement would be “S is **less than** the surface beneath [a, b] but **greater than** the surface beneath [a + 1, b + 1].” If your write the “surface” as an integral then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the "step" function given by $s_1(x)=\frac{1}{k}, \quad x \in [k,k+1[$. Since $s_1(x) \ge \frac 1x$, the same inequality holds for the respective integrals, i.e
$$
\int_{a+1}^{b+1} s_1(x) dx \ge \int_{a+1}^{b+1} \frac 1x \, dx
$$

Now, the LHS is your sum $S$ and the RHS is $\log \frac{b+1}{a+1}$. So, we conclude that 
$$
\sum_{i=a+1}^b \frac{1}{i} \ge \log \frac{b+1}{a+1}.
$$

The other inequality can be obtained in a similar manner by considering $s_2(x) = \frac{1}{k+1}, \quad x \in [k,k+1[$.